# Import SCORM package in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, moodle, scorm

Failing to import SCORM package PHP/MySQL.

I am creating my own SCORM package in the laravel framework but I didn't get any kind of independent package with which I am able to create my own package without using Moodle.

I have looked at the link https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/SCORMCloud_PHPLibrary but it's not useful for me. Please suggest a solution to import SCORM package.

Is there any solution/approach to import SCORM package in PHP without Moodle?

Comment: It is not as simple as you make it sound, SCORM is a set of standards for eLearning that were developed in the late 90's. These are a set of practices for developing e-Learning tools, as opposed to some type of integral programming functionality. Because of that, we cannot give you assistance in any clear or concise way, making this question too broad for us to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Moodle, I do not know of any free or opensource library that does what you are asking for, but if you look around you may find that its all just puzzle pieces you can put together.

### Basic Recipe (roll your own):

1. PHP: Unzip the CAM/PIF to a location on your server.
2. PHP: Validate imsmanifest.xml (optional using xsd validators)
3. PHP: Parse imsmanifest.xml (scorm version, objects and resources)
4. PHP/DB: Put data in Assignments Table or Lesson Structure
5. PHP/DB: Create assignment to student(s) or Class or however you like
6. PHP/DB: Provide API/Script for providing the Student Runtime (Attempt).  This could be JSON, or like Moodle just a ton of defined vars for JavaScript.
7. JavaScript: Create a Runtime API for SCORM (Initialize, Get/SetValue, Commit, Terminate) SCORM 2004, for 1.2 they are a little different.
8. Provide API/Script for ingesting modified Student Attempt (data) on Commit call.

The most difficult of all this is 7 and 8.  Depending on how "complete" you make it will stretch out your dev time.  I'd roughly estimate rolling your own SCORM Runtime after consuming all the Whitepapers to take up to 2 years.
This is mainly why you don't find a *free* option.
Most of SCORM 1.2's data model (cmi object) was mainly optional (vs required).  So you can choose to only support the required features of it and drastically reduce your dev time.  Their are thousands of pages of whitepapers on these standards which are based on IEEE, IMS, and other consortium's which contributed to them.